# Relationship between stock and product

Tags: database-design

I have a database should store sales, I created a table for **products** and one more table for **stock** I felt the relationship between them is **many-to-many** because a product in one stock may have different price from another stock, and one stock can have many products, so I created another table for create a relationship between these two tables by name of **Stock_Product**, but Now I fell it is wrong, because every time when I want to query from **Sales** table which contains the sales records I need to join 4 tables for selecting the details of product and stock.

Comment: I voted to close as it's unclear what your actual question is. Perhaps if you were able to explain why you have the many to many relationship and the stock table (stock in multiple warehouses?) then we may be able to help. An ERD would help to.

Comment: Hmmm... it seems to me that no matter where the product comes from, it has one and only one product_id at the point of sale. It may have different suppliers - so then you want a 1 -> many product_id to SKU - is this for accounting purposes? Unless I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

So a single product can potentially have multiple prices at once? If this is the case then I don't see the need for the extra table. Create the products table, including product name, description plus whatever else you need. Then create the stock table, with a FK relationship to the products table product ID with quantity and price per unit. When a sale is made it can take the price from the stock table and enter it as a sale price in the sales table and update the quantity in the stock table.

The only thing that isn't clear is where you said a stock can have multiple products. The above seems to be a better method of handling this rather than having a product with multiple stock records and stock records with multiple products.